# tradehill.com alternative?

Tags: commerce, ecommerce, tradehill

I am constructing a small online store where I would like to accept BitCoins as payment.

I have not had any luck running the Deamon on my server, so I was planning to use tradehill.com and then make use of the API.

But every time I log in i get the

> "Socket not connected Sorry, our notification socket isn't connected
>   yet. Try again in a few seconds!"

Error... And it's making me kind of anxious to use the system, since it seems a bit derelict.

Does anyone know any similar systems ? Or know what's going on backstage of TradeHill.com ?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question might interest you: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-can-i-accept-bitcoins-on-my-website

Comment: You may want to consider an alternative approach using a combination of MultiBit and MultiBit Merchant. This will allow you to run your online store without putting any private keys on it. At the time of writing it's still early alpha, but progressing fast. See https://github.com/gary-rowe/MultiBitMerchant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have technical problems with Tradehill, your first step should be to contact them about it.

It's not clear to me in what capacity you want to replace Tradehill. If you want an exchange then Mt. Gox is an obvious possibility, or any one of the exchanges listed [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Currency_exchanges). If you want an eWallet, most exchanges are good for this too, and flexcoin is another possibility. If you want merchant solutions, check out [bitpay](https://bit-pay.com/).

Comment: I have tried getting in touch with TradeHill for a week or two, but without any luck.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I don't often hear complaints about Tradehill's customer service, and I often recommend Tradehill to people. I hope they are able to resume being responsive to customers.

Comment: It's ok. Still no contact, so concidering making my own little system.