# Can Bitcoin be run in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: bitcoind, server, installation, hosting

Can bitcoind be installed and run on shared hosting? Has anyone successfully done this? If not why not.

Comment: `bitcoind` is a daemon, it needs a shell to run: a web host is definitely not enough. But maybe I misunderstood your question. What do you _exactly_ need?

Comment: Attempting to run bitcoin on godaddy shared hosting

Comment: But why do you want to do that, what do you need to do exactly? (anyway the answer is NO, you can't do that)

Comment: A 3rd party service can probably achieve it. Voting to keep this open.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular he doesn't even understand what he is saying, he has no idea what he wants and fails to explain it to us. This is one of the worst questions I've ever read, I'm stunned knowing that two people upvoted it...

Comment: Actually the question was more clear before it was edited. I'd like t know how to run bitcoind on linux shared hosting if that's possible.

Comment: "shared hosting" can mean many things.  There is no blanket yes or no answer for this question.

Comment: I see, originally the question was more specific though it was subsequently edited. I'm wondering about CentOS Godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept bitcoins on my website?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-can-i-accept-bitcoins-on-my-website)

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoind` is a daemon, it needs a shell to run: a web host is definitely not enough.

Comment: What's a shell? "A shell is software that provides an interface for users of an operating system to access the services of a kernel." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)

Comment: You need shell access to a real server. If you don't understand that, I'm sorry but not only you can't do what you think you want to do, but you actually do not even _understand_ what you want to do.

Comment: I figured someone else reading the question might not understand the language.

Comment: yes bitcoind need a shell access, and most shared hosting wont provide that, you will need full ssh access to the server for a bitcoind to run.

Comment: Most shared hosting plans offer SSH access these days.

Answer (score 0):

A full instance of bitcoind or the client isn't needed.

You probably are looking for a "checkout button" to a server that will either host your wallet for you or will cash out on demand.

There are many, but [MtGox has one](https://mtgox.com/merchant/checkout) and I'm pretty sure [Bitpay](https://bitpay.com) has one as well.  This isn't a comprehensive list, but the concept is that you add a "button" to your website that facilities payment.  This button works with ASP.NET, PHP and anything else that generates HTML.

Note that although it may be possible for static HTML pages to be supported, I haven't investigated if its possible. (You haven't indicated if you're using plain old HTML or a dynamic language)

Comment: How could a checkou button be implemented using either static or dynamic HTML?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Have you or a developer investigated those links I posted?  Are you asking how to place the HTML into a webpage?  Are you asking a programming question?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of both of those. I imagine they run on dedicated servers or VPS's.

Comment: Your response is not an answer to the questions I asked.  Although I want to help you, I can't help you since it is too difficult for me to get the information I need from you.  Your question isn't detailed enough or you're not asking the right question.

Comment: I'm asking about a bitcoin node running in a shared hosting environment. Would you categorize this as a programming question?

Comment: No because I don't know what you're asking.  Can you run bitcoind on a server? yes.  Linux? sure.  Shared hosting? Probably, depends on the provider.

Answer (score 0):

bitcoind is an application. Shared web hosts generally do not allow custom applications. They have `php`, `rails`, etc which runs user **scripts** but not applications.

You will need a VPS or dedicated server where you can install your own applications.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.
But you keep an application open running it ,as you would a php torrent tracker.
But the requirements won't be met for the depencies required.

So that being said.

Means yes ,but because of lacked dependency issues , that's the only thing stopping you. You need small cheap vps.
Download a little SH file edit it and put proper depency files tonbe installef ,and you should be good to go.

Sidenote: Many people will not help you with such a thing. They will say off the wall things out if ingnorance or jealousy. BUT remember running such a thing like that deamon ,or mining from shared hosting can get your account nailed with no return of money.
Because it's a violation of shared hosting terms.

Good luck.