# How to use my own web hosting server to mine a bitcoin?

Tags: client, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, multibit, bitcoinj

I have a web hosting with unlimited bandwidth and unlimited disk space, Cpanel and much more. Can anyone guide me. How to mine a bitcoin by using my own web hosting?. Then there is any mining software is available to install into my web hosting?. please anyone help me to find out the solution.

**Note**: I am not consider the hash rate and money. If it is possible I will try otherwise i am not doing anything?

Thank You!

Comment: I highly doubt your web host will allow this.

Comment: See also: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/can-bitcoin-be-run-in-a-shared-hosting-environment/8548#8548

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as `ssh`ing into your server and installing a bitcoin miner such as [this one](https://github.com/lithander/Minimal-Bitcoin-Miner). A server is just a computer and a bitcoin miner is just a program so as long as you can install programs via a terminal you should have no problem and any old getting stated bitcoin mining guide should work.

That being said, this is generally not a good idea to do. Bitcoin mining has gotten to the point where to be cost effective you have to use custom built chips. This means that if you mine bitcoins on a regular old web server making use of the CPU or even the GPU, you will loose money on electricity + server costs.

If you truly do have unlimited free webserver time, then hell, go for it, but understand that this is a net capital loss, your just externalizing the cost to your server provider.

Comment: "That being said, this is generally not a good idea to do."