# Using bitcoin in a startup company

Tags: payment-processors, website-integration

We are a start up company going to open an online shopping website. Our CEO wants to incorporate Bitcoin as our payment method. How can we set up a Bitcoin network?

Comment: You might want to consult an article such as https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_accept_Bitcoin,_for_small_businesses which has a ton of links to relevant products and services.

Comment: also see this related question: [How can I accept bitcoins on my website?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/126/5406)

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the merchant solution providers, such as:
coinbase, BitPay, for generating addresses per payment (as paypal does) redirects / serve the client with payment request at 3rd party . 
or, you can handle payment process inhouse by generating address for each payment and saving the pk / HD wallet will take much longer and develop time to do.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your custom solution using language specific library (for example NBitcoin for C#).
2. Your custom solution using bitoind and JSON-RPC communication protocol.
3. Integration with Bitcoin payments processor - this is the simplest but your money are kept and managed by foregin company for some time and probably you have to pay for the service.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the previous answer said...?

Comment: Yes, but without grammar and vocabulary mistakes ;)

Comment: If you want to propose corrections to an existing answer, it's better to [suggest an edit](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/40453/edit) rather than posting a new, duplicative answer.

Comment: I can't imageine how anyone could edit and repair this part of the answear "request at 3rd party . or, you can handle" :D

Comment: Whole answaeer is just one big sentence with mess. I don't understand what author want to say, the answear should deleted