# Multibit + WooCommerce

Tags: altcoin

I would like to incorporate MultiBit into a wordpress(woocommerce) based site I am designing as a checkout/payment option.

Is this at all possible and if so how do I go about it?
I cannot find any resources or tutorials on the web on how to do this.

Thank you for your time.
Peter.

Comment: related: [How can I accept bitcoins on my website?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/126/5406)