# Where can I learn the basics of making a wallet site?

Tags: e-wallet, payment-processors, website-integration

So like lets say I want to make a website that accepts btc deposits and withdrawals like this https://www.cryptonator.com/ where would i learn how to do that where do i go to learn the basics? I know this is quite a basic question but it is hard for me to know where to look for this in the pandemic finding a job has not been very easy and i need something to keep me going.

Comment: You can start here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-can-i-accept-bitcoins-on-my-website

Comment: You should try to reuse existing implementations as much as possible. Implementing a wallet may seem easy but coin safety is crucial.